# Generic type provider with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying to inject typed object into service class but getting

```
    com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for com.bookpac.utils.appserver.ILookup<com.bookpac.server.common.IWS> was bound.
  while locating com.bookpac.utils.appserver.ILookup<com.bookpac.server.common.IWS>
    for parameter 0 at com.bookpac.server.LookupService.<init>(LookupService.java:13)
  while locating com.bookpac.server.LookupService
```

Field to be injected is `ILookup<IWS> lookup`, 
binding is `bind(ILookup.class).toProvider(LookupProvider.class)`

When using @Provides annotation everything works fine, any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use generic types you need to use a TypeLiteral like :

`bind(new TypeLiteral<ILookup<IWS>>(){}).toProvider(LookupProvider.class);`

From the [documentation](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html)  :

> Java doesn't yet provide a way to represent generic types, so this
>   class does.