# Guice Generic Provider (the Provider itself is generic, not the class it's binding to)

Tags: java, inheritance, dependency-injection, guice, constructor-injection

There are a lot of online resources about how to use a Guice Provider to bind to a generic class, such as [wiki entries like this](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) and [SOF questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071028/generic-type-provider-with-guice). However, I am having trouble finding a resource about how to use a Provider that is generic itself.

For example, lets say I have the following:

```
public interface Foo {
    ...
}

public class Bar implements Foo {
    ...
}
```

As you can see, Bar has an injection parameter that MUST be in the constructor. In my situation, we cannot move this parameter to field or method injection.

So, now I want to write a Provider for Foo, but that it returns an instance of Bar. Something like this:

```
@Singleton
public class FooProvider<T extends Foo> extends Provider<Foo> {
    @Inject
    public FooProvider(Object someParameterWeMustInjectIntoConstructor) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public Foo get() {
        return new Bar(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

Notice how this class is a singleton that relies on Guice injection itself, so the Provider must be configured using `.toProvider(FooProvider.class)`. We also can only use constructor injection and not method nor field injection, possibly because of a type hierarchy with this Provider.

I am trying to find some sort of was to use `.toProvider(FooProvider<Bar>.class)`, but we all know that this is not valid Java syntax. Does anyone know how I can use the `.toProvider(Class<? extends Provider>)` method of a Guice binder in a Module so I can use a generic Provider to create a concrete class of an implementation? Let me know if my question is a little confusing.

Comment: You have to use reflection

Comment: It is not clear why do you have to use `FooProvider<T extends Foo> extends Provider<Foo>` instead of, say, `FooBarProvider extends Provider<Foo> { ... return new Bar(...); }`. If you really need such a thing, could you please elaborate *why* do you need it?

Comment: The answer I accepted is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
toProvider(new TypeLiteral<FooProvider<Bar>>() { });
```

Comment: `toProvider` expects a `Provider`, not a `TypeLiteral`.

Comment: Couldn't figure out the link syntax in time, let's try [this](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/binder/LinkedBindingBuilder.html#toProvider%28com.google.inject.TypeLiteral%3C?%20extends%20javax.inject.Provider%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%3E%29).

Comment: AWESOME! Not sure how I missed this one in the JavaDoc.